# Javascript Global Variables not initializing

Tags: javascript, html, input, global-variables

I am making a webpage that that gets input from text boxes (). The page also has three buttons that perform different functions. These functions share many variables so I made most of the variables global. My problem is that when I input text into the text boxes and click a button the function runs but the global variables don't initialize so the function can't run properly. I need the variables to initialize before the function runs.
I have cut the code down to as simple as I can to still show the problem. My original code had three buttons and three functions which is why I need to use global variables.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <body>
     <form>
     <br><input type="text" class="boxleft" placeholder="type here..." id="Age"/>

     <br> <input type="text" id="retireAge" class="boxleft" placeholder="type here..." />
     </form>

      <button id="test" onclick="CalcNW()" >Test</button>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       //global variables
       var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
       var rage = document.getElementById("retireAge").value;

      function CalcNW() {
      var workingyears = rage - age;
      alert(workingyears);
      }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example the function would not work properly because rage and age would be empty.
Is there anyway to get the global variables to initialize before it runs any of the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is bad design. Even if you wish to keep your variables global, you should evaluate the value in the form upon function click. What's happening is that javascript is populating the values immediately, probably, before the dom has finished loading. Also, when you're defining globals based on application state, it's best to add a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) handler. Have fun developing. :)

Perhaps, you can do something like this:

```
age = 0;
rage  0;

function CalcNW() {
    getInput();
    var workingyears = rage - age;
    alert(workingyears);
}

function getInput(){
    age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
    rage = document.getElementById("retireAge").value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. And thank you for the advice, I am a fairly new coder so any advice helps

Comment: No worries. Enjoy and have fun. :) I suggest reading up on this book when you have time. http://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your js code in window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
      var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
      var rage = document.getElementById("retireAge").value;

      function CalcNW() {
          var workingyears = rage - age;
          alert(workingyears);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //global variables
        var age, rage;

        function CalcNW() {
            age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
            rage = document.getElementById("retireAge").value;
            var workingyears = rage - age;
            alert(workingyears);
        }
```

Why not declare your variables outside of your function, and set them inside of it?